# Other than save_post any other actions on add / edit post screen?

Tags: admin, actions

When the add post or edit post screens load, is there an action other than save_post which I can hook on to? I need to make an API request before a user starts adding / editing posts. Basically when the add or edit post screen loads I need my API call to be made. I know that `save_post` first when those pages are loaded, i'm just wondering if there is an earlier action I can hook on to? I've looked at http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference and do not see any useful other than `save_post`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `load-{page-hook}`. It is called prior to the admin screen loading.

```
add_action( 'load-post-new.php', 'post_listing_page' );
function post_listing_page() {
    // 'add new' page, you may have to check post type..
}
```

- {page-hook} on the 'add new' page of any post type, it is post-new.php
- {page-hook} on the edit page of any post type, it is post.php